# How to find how many strong references for a object in heap/stack at runtime

Tags: java, c, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Team,

Is there possible in java, to know how many active/strong  references for a object currently available ?

For example in the below code; Object of class A can be hold by many classes in the project. But i want to print that in the monitor thread.

```
public class A {
  public static A a = new A();
  public static A getInstance() {
     return a;
  }

  private A() {
     new Monitor(this).start();
  }


  class Monitor extends Thread {
      A refA;
      public Monitor(A ref) {
         this.refA = ref;
      }
      public void run () {

      //TODO Print how many references currently available for Object A referenced by refA;
      //Sure It will be minimum one. (which is "a" in this class A)   
      } 

   }
}
```

Please don't give much importance to this example program. My question is how to find how many strong references available to an object in the heap/stack? Only good thing is we have one strong reference in hand for that object.

If it is not possible in java; can i pass this strong reference to C language; and from C language can i able to do that?

I just wonder how the Profilers/tools are able to do this?
Please help.

Comment: I want to execute some action when there is only one active references after calling getInstance(). Means the caller method of getInstance() is ended in the stack. So we have only one active reference which is 'a'.

Comment: Looks more like you need some kind of Aspect capability, try AspectJ or Spring AOP.

Comment: Do you need only the "up"-flank or both? I mean is it that you need to do something 1) once when the count is turning from 0 to 1, 2) everytime the count turns from 0 to 1, 3) everytime the count turns from X!=1 to 1?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't get the exact count without changing the class or branch tools on the VM (which can hardly be made in production due to the impact on performances).

Using [the ref package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html), you can be notified if an object is about to be garbaged (and act at this time) but there is no count available (and not always one handled by the VM).

Comment: Fine. Could you please tell me how profilers/Tools are able to do? Is it possible in C langauge? Then can i use native call ?

Comment: You can't do this without severely impacting performances, because modern JVM don't even keep a count of the instances.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide any suggestion on my conversion with Peter Lawrey?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a heap dump and analyse it to find the number of references to any object.

What is your requirement for doing this and what will you do with the information as I suspect there is an easier/better way to achieve what you want.

---

Based on WeakHashMap

```
/**
 * Reference queue for cleared WeakEntries
 */
private final ReferenceQueue<Connection> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();

List<WeakReference<Connection>> usedConnections = ....

// when you have a new connection

Connection connection = ....
usedConnections.add(new WeakReference(connection, queue));

// checking the queue for discarded objects.

    // remove null references from usedConnections

    for (Connection x; (x = queue.poll()) != null; ) {
        synchronized (queue) {
           x.close();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Around 700 places in code DB connection object requested from the pool; But they never closed.  This is not seen since max_no_connection_size is 75. Found only during the load test. I just want solution instead making code changes on all the files; how i can close it pool side itself?

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak.  I would use a memory profiler to see where they are being retained. Are you closing your JDBC resources like PreparedStatements are well?

Comment: That code never closed connection even a single place. So it is now difficult to change to all these 700 places. So any suggestion how i can rectify this?

Comment: The connections could be kept open by not cleaning up the resources using the connections. The real fix is to fix the code. Any work around is unlikely to work as you think it should as just closing the connections won't be enough.

Comment: Statements along with resultset are closed properly in all those places. But the connection is not closed or not returned to the pool. One thing i can say the reference may be ended once transaction block is over but not freed. Because of this before GC i get exception from the pool that max conn reached. So i want to do if there is no active reference to this conn object then close/return to the pool by monitor thread. But how..?? :(

Comment: What you can do in this situation is place all the connections in a collection of WeakReferences.  The WeakReferences can share a ReferenceQueue. (See WeakHashMap source as an example)  What this does is add any weak referenced object which is discarded to the ReferenceQueue so you can do what you need before the object is discarded.

Comment: No This won't help since GC itself will close the connection. Why should i think after GC. My problem is Before GC (GC is not guaranteed & only at memory shortage) I have to check is there any connection object is eligible for GC if yes i have to close()/revert it to the pool.

Comment: In that case, when your connection pool fills up you just need to trigger a GC to clean up resources. To reduce how often GCs are triggered this way you need to fix the code which fails to return the connection to the pool the most often. (rather than all the code)

Answer (score -2):

You may try out somthing like this

```
Class A
{
   static int instanceCount = 0;
   public A()
   {
      instanceCount++;
   }

   protected finalize()
   {
      instanceCount--;
   }

   public static int getInstanceCount()
   {
       return instanceCount;
   }
}
```

I believe this is the closest you can get to conting references of a class using code. Hope it helps ...

Comment: Hope you know the references will be ended once the getInstance() caller method block of code ends. It will never be the same as number of getInstance() called in runtime. Also we can't get help from finalize() also since we are talking about references of alive object.

Comment: in your above example the instance count is always 1 for one ClassLoader. Now in JVM even same classes loaded by different Classloaders are treated as different classes. So in your case the number of instances = number of classloaders loading class A.